# Add users/groups and roles to Azure AD native app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When I register an application of type `Web App/API` in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), I can add Users and Groups and assign pre-defined application roles to the application in the tenant's Enterprise Applications. However, there is no provision to add Users and Groups for an application of type `Native`.

Is it possible to add Users and Groups to a native application, and set them with application specific roles via PowerShell or Azure CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed Users and Groups is hidden in the Enterprise Applications blade in the case of native applications and I believe that the reason is that you don't usually configure role assignments in the native application but instead you do it in the WebApp/WebAPI (that the native application is consuming).

Anyway yes you can configure application roles for a native application. You can do it but editing the manifest and adding the appRole there (the value property will appear in the role claim). Example:

```
  "appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application",
        "User"
      ],
      "displayName": "ReadOnly",
      "id": "9cc5ee76-3d7d-4060-8b7f-e734f3917e71",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "ReadOnly roles have limited query access",
      "value": "ReadOnlyUser"
    }
  ]
```

Then you can add an user to that role by using Powershell:

```
New-AzureADUserAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId <user's object ID> -PrincipalId <user's object ID> -ResourceId <native app service principal ID> -Id <role ID as it is in the manifest>
```

Then if you get a token for this application and for that user, you should see the role claim:

```
  "roles": [
    "ReadOnlyUser"
  ]
```

Comment: I am trying to create a REST API (Web API) that will internally use Microsoft Graph API to manage users in an Azure AD tenant. Only users in specific roles need to be able to access the API. This API will be consumed by an mobile app. I implemented a _headless_ login by setting up the REST application as a native app in Azure AD, so the mobile user can log in using just the username and password. But native apps don't allow setting up Users/ Groups/ Roles under Enterprise Applications. But if I set up the REST app as a Web App/API, then I cannot do the headless login. That's the problem.